# why is this joi regex validation for hex color failing

Tags: hapi.js, joi

Why is this regex should match but it's failing?

error

`child "color" fails because ["color" with value "#333acf " fails to match the required pattern: /^#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}$/]`

```
  validate: {
        payload:{
            avatar: joi.object().keys({
              color: joi.string().regex(/^#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}$/),
              icon: joi.string().min(2)
          })
        }
    }
```

payload

```
{
    "avatar": {color:"#333acf ",icon:"b1"}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your color string has an extra space at the end. Should be

```
{
    "avatar": {color:"#333acf",icon:"b1"}
}
```

or your regex needs to allow strings longer than 6 characters by removing the end of string anchor.

```
/^#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}/
```

Comment: it should be 6 characters after the # mark, which I think is what it's testing - shows up as valid regex in testing https://regex101.com/r/dW5mR1/1

Comment: The string in the payload section of your original question is "#333acf ", with 7 characters. It should be "#333acf", with 6 characters.

Comment: lol, yes it was that extra space.   I removed the space from the input and it works fine now.